# Solving the 24 Game for 5, 5, 5 and 1

Tags: recreational-mathematics

> The [24 Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24_Game) is an arithmetical card game in which the objective is to find a way to manipulate four integers so that the end result is 24.
>
> How do you get $24$ using $5, 5, 5,$ and $1?$

Solution: $\displaystyle5\times\left[5-\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)\right].$

Comment: Define $x,y,z,w\mapsto 24$, then $5,5,5,1\mapsto 24$.

Comment: In the "24 game" I have on my phone, only $+$, $-$, $\cdot$, $/$ and parentheses are allowed - you should clarify if that is also what you intended with this question (it would invalidate all the current answers).

Comment: @Henrik Spoil-sport

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD I *loved* that comment, especially since I used this game when teaching pre-algebra students about order of operations. I think the mapping concept would have been too much though (well maybe not...looking back, I am quite annoyed I was not introduced to the concept of a mapping until far later than I should have been). Fwiw, [this site](http://scripts.cac.psu.edu/staff/r/j/rjg5/scripts/Math24.pl?a=5&b=5&c=5&d=1) gives 10 easy solutions right away.

Comment: Can this just be moved to the mathematics puzzle section?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution using just the $+$, $-$, $\times$, $/$ operations, and parentheses:
$$
5 \times (5 - (1/5))
$$

Answer (score 5):

With [Euler's Totient function](https://oeis.org/A000010/list):

$$\phi(5 \cdot 5) + \phi(5 \cdot 1)$$

Answer (score 4):

Here is one for you guys

$$ -1^5 + 5*5 $$

Comment: Where does the $2$'s come from? And what does $(5)$ mean?

Comment: sorry i did prime factorization. edited

Comment: You should add $$ around the expression.

Answer (score 3):

One possible answer is $$5 \cdot 5 - \lceil \frac{1}{5} \rceil$$

Answer (score 3):

One easy way:

$$(5-1)!\cdot\frac{5}5$$

Answer (score 2):

Or $$\sqrt{5\cdot 5} \cdot5  - 1$$

Answer (score 2):

$1\times\frac{5}{5}\Gamma(5){}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Care to elaborate a bit?

Comment: Gamma function $\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!$

Comment: Was a bit of a silly answer, although it's true. @John for $n \in \Bbb Z^+$

Answer (score 1):

One possible way:

$$(5-5)+(5-1)!=24$$

Answer (score 1):

With [derangements](https://oeis.org/A000166/list):

$$!5 - 5(5 - 1)$$